# Launch an SWF full screen

Tags: python, flash, firefox, bash, browser

I have a `swf` file (a flash game). I want to run some script to open it in full-screen mode. I'm not attached to any browser, but I do run Linux, so a bash, or generic answer is what I'm looking for. I'm also open to building a lite browser application if need-be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SWF can be launched in full screen in several ways, here comes some suggested solutions:

1) You can open the SWF-file directly (works for me, in Firefox).

2) You can add a HTML page with this JavaScript that redirects to your SWF-file.

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
    document.location.href='packman.swf'; 
</script>
```

3) You can embed the SWF-file in a HTML page.

Answer (score 0):

i think this might do it if you put it in the initialization part:

`Stage["displayState"]="fullScreen";`

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Is this flash code? I don't have access to the code for the SWF. I'm looking for an easy way to script the opening and transition to full-screen for an arbitrary flash file.

Comment: sorry, didnt read entire question, missed "Linux, so a bash, or generic"